# GraphQL is returning "Names must match" error when the Key is of type integer

Tags: graphql

I am trying to use `GraphQL` with a legacy service which returns a JSON with some of the keys as integer. Here is an example,

```
{
  "id": 1234,
  "image": {
    "45": "image1url",
    "90": "image2url"
  },
  "name": "I am legacy server"
}
```

When I tried to define `"45`" as `GraphQL` field,

```
var imageType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Image',
  fields: {
    45: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
    90: { type: graphql.GraphQLString }
  }
});
```

I am getting the following error,

> Error: Names must match /^[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$/ but "45" does not`.

How can we handle keys as integer scenario?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GraphQL only allows keys starting with ASCII character or an underscore. You can use `resolve` functions to map old names to new.

```
var imageType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Image',
  fields: {
    size45: { 
      type: graphql.GraphQLString,
      resolve: (parent) => parent['45'],
    },
    size90: { 
      type: graphql.GraphQLString,
      resolve: (parent) => parent['90']
    }
  }
});
```